# "war is" and "there are wars"

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, abstract-nouns

> War **is** horrific. But there **are** war**s** happening in places in the world right now.

Did I make any mistakes? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

War is a horrible thing. And yet there are places in the world where war is in full swing as we speak.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. But is there any mistake in my sentences. And can we just say "War is horrible"

Comment: There are no mistakes per say, just some awkwardness.  Using "But" in the beginning of a sentence is not a good practice unless you really, really know what you're doing. Try replacing it with "That said," or "However." "Happening" isn't a happy choice in this case. "going on" or even "occurring" or "taking place" would be better.  "in places in the world" is ... uh ... well, redundant. Or something. "in various localities AROUND the world" would be better.

Comment: Oh, and I liked your question a lot, which is why I pressed the upward-pointing triangle to give it a +1. I would appreciate it if you returned the favor, i.e. pressed the appropriate triangle next to my answer - since you like it so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. Do we have to use the word "war" singularly, can it be "wars"

Comment: You can use either war or wars. Don't give up on your original attempt, though, if your writing naturally tends towards minimalism. I am a minimalist myself.

Comment: Downvote b/c there is no explanation in the answer. All the useful stuff is in the comments, and as you know comments often get wiped out. I'd be happy to retract DV and UV if the answer is improved.